# Evitar chamadas sucessivas de getElementById com o mesmo parâmetro

Tags: javascript

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
function valida_form (){

        var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|-|_|\s)+$/ ;
        if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
            document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
            document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
            document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
            document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
            document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
            return false;
        }
}
```

No código existem várias interações realizadas em um elemento com o mesmo "ID", existe alguma forma de chamá-lo apenas 1 vez ?

Comment: Por que não salvar o resultado do `getElementById` numa variável?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Sou totalmente newb em javascript, é possível você utilizando o código acima, expor uma solução via código, pls...

Comment: @MagicHat, experimentou usar `<input id='input_nome_cad' type='text' pattern='^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|-|_|\s)+$' title='Nome inválido' />` e definir um css para caso o input seja invalido: `#input_nome_cad:invalid { borderColor: red; outline: red; }`?

Comment: @TobyMosque é pq estou evitando HTML5... Se pode me ajudar nessa dúvida aqui (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131579/retornar-div-ao-estilo-anterior-ap%C3%B3s-ter-alterado-estilo-somente-com-javascrip) ? Vê se se consegue me ajuda nessa...pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pode segmentar as rotinas e utilizar em diversos inputs

```js
function valida_nome(value) {
  var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|-|_|\s)+$/;
  return filter_nome.test(value);
};

function layout_error(input) {
  input.value = '';
  input.placeholder = "Nome inválido";
  input.focus();
  input.style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
  input.style.outline = "#ff0000";
};

function layout_ok(input) {
  //input.style.borderColor = "#EFEFEF";
  //input.style.outline = "#EFEFEF";
  input.style = null;
};

function valida_form() {
  var campoDeNome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad");

  if (!valida_nome(campoDeNome.value)) {
    layout_error(campoDeNome)
    return false;
  }
  layout_ok(campoDeNome);
  return true;
};
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return false;">
  <input type="text" name="input_nome_cad" id="input_nome_cad" />
  <button type="button" onclick="valida_form()">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução simples é criar uma variável local à sua função para guardar o resultado e usar essa variável dali em diante:

```
function valida_form(){

    var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|-|_|\s)+$/ ;
    var campoDeNome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad");

    if(!filter_nome.test(campoDeNome.value)){
        campoDeNome.value='';
        campoDeNome.placeholder = "Nome inválido";
        campoDeNome.focus();
        campoDeNome.style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
        campoDeNome.style.outline = "#ff0000";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Se você está usando JQuery, você pode aproveitar o fato de que as funções do JQuery costumam retornar o próprio objeto JQuery modificado/requisitado, o que possibilita o **encadeamento** (*chaining*) de chamadas.

Um exemplo (incompleto, mas dá pra ter uma ideia) seria:

```
$('#input_nome_cad').val('')
    .attr('placeholder', 'Nome inválido')
    .focus()
    .css('border-top-color', '#ff0000');
```

Comment: tá faltando a validação do regex dá uma olhada! `if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){`

Comment: Ops. Verdade. Obrigado. :)

Comment: @Pablo Almeida Entendi seu ponto de vista, mas nesse caso estou chamando a variável várias vezes, eu busco uma solução para minimizar as chamadas e aplicar somente as ações pretendidas. Nem sempre o que se busca é possível, mas vou dar mais uma fuçada... Vwl

Comment: Não existe "chamar variável". Existe chamar método. O método está sendo chamado apenas uma vez. Acredito que você está tentando otimizar onde não precisa.

Comment: @Pablo Almeida Entendi seu ponto de vista, mas nesse caso estou "reutilizando" a variável , eu busco uma solução para minimizar a "reutilização" e aplicar somente as ações pretendidas. A questão da necessidade é pessoal, agradeço da mesma forma.

Comment: @MagicHat Dê uma olhada na edição.