# Retornar div ao estilo anterior, após ter alterado estilo, somente com javascript

Tags: javascript

Código:

```js
function valida_form (){
 
  var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|-|_|\s)+$/ ;
  if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
  document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
  document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
  document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
  document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
  document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
  return false;}
  }
```

O código acima faz uma verificação em um "input text", caso o campo não seja válido, as alterações no estilo são realizadas.

No entanto, após realizar o preenchimento correto do campo e saltar para o próximo, o campo onde o estilo  foi alterado permanece alterado, como voltar ao estilo original, após o preenchimento correto do campo ?

Comment: como você disse se um pouco novo com JavaScript, dá uma lida neste site: [H5F.js](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/H5F),  lá ele explica muita coisa sobre a implementação blibioteca em questao.

Comment: @TobyMosque bem interessante, mas acredito ser mais fácil aprender de forma procedural do que classes e bibliotecas, acho que sou meio conservador meio oldschool, o que nåo nos liberta de um paradoxo em relação a tecnologias...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando jQuery

```
element.removeAttr('style'); 
element.removeAttr('placeholder');
```

eu pessoalmente aconcelho-te a fazeres as alterações numa classe como eu mostro [aqui neste jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bertolo/168LL767/)

---

Com JavaScript Nativo podes fazer assim:

```
function meteEstilo() {
    var element = document.getElementById('myInput');
    element.classList.add('estilo-novo');
    element.setAttribute('placeholder', 'inválido!');
}

function tiraEstilo() {
    var element = document.getElementById('myInput');
    element.classList.remove('estilo-novo');
    element.removeAttribute('placeholder', '');
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/168LL767/3/

Comment: vlw mas é que eu queria no puro javascript...

Comment: acrescentei, vê lá se ajuda

Comment: Se eu aplicar removeAttribute, ele irá remover o atributo, eu gostaria que ele voltasse ao primeiro estilo. Me corrija se eu estiver errado...

Comment: var originalStyle =document.getElementById('sample_id').getAttribute('style'); Guardas isso algures e depois fazes set se quiseres retornar ao original.

Comment: Ainda assim a melhor solução, sem duvida, é introduzir a class de css com as alterações necessárias. Depois é só tira-la para voltar ao original.

Comment: tipo assim o cara digita um nome errado no campo, daí aparece o placeholder "Nome errado" e a borda vermelha, daí o cara corrigi e salta pro próximo campo, nesse momento o campo que tava vermelho volta ao normal, mas eu tava pensando algo do tipo if else, ou while(enquanto os dados do campo não atenderem ao regex fica vermelho se naum fica como tá)... Sei que talvez eu esteja complicando , mas eu gostaria de ver um código tipo para retornar o estado anterior e não adicionar um novo estilo...Liga naum sou pura confusão...

Comment: então mas o que mostrei no jsfiddle foi exactamente isso, so que em vez de usar validação acrescentei as alterações por intermédio de butões

Comment: Num leva a mal mai tá em jquery, dá pra alterar no puro javascript? É que sou total newb...

Answer (score 2):

Tanto no seu primeiro if quanto no caso de passar no teste, você pode alterar as propriedades de style do elemento com setAttribute dessa forma:

```
 //Esse de acordo com o seu código no caso falha.
 document.getElementById('input_nome_cad').setAttribute('style', 'border-color : #ff0000; outline : #ff0000;');
```

No caso de passar no teste é só alterar as propriedades, mas particularmente eu prefiro trabalhar com classes css do que css inline, mas isso é escolha sua, no caso de uso de classes é só fazer:

```
 document.getElementById('input_nome_cad').setAttribute('class', 'suaClasse');
```

Sua função ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
function valida_form (){

    var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|-|_|\s)+$/ ;     
    if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
       document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
       document.getElementById('input_nome_cad').setAttribute('placeholder', 'Nome inválido');
       document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
       document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").setAttribute('style', 'border-color : #ff0000; outline : #ff0000;');
       return false;
    }
    else{
       document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").setAttribute('style', 'border-color : #000000;');      
       document.getElementById('input_nome_cad').setAttribute('placeholder', '');
       //ou document.getElementById('input_nome_cad').removeAttribute('placeholder');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Eu não estou sabendo montar o if else...Tem como se emendar lá no código, tô meio perdido, na verdade acho que fritou o tico...Tipo são 4 estados,1 o normal (em branco), 2 se passa no teste normal num muda nada, 3 se num passa dai muda, 4 se o cara corrige e passa dai fica normal...

Comment: Dá uma olhada lá, acho que isso  resolve, qualquer coisa é só ajustar agora.